# My nephew is 10 years old, he does not read the exam questions properly which leads to many mistakes although he knows the answer, what can I do?

Tags: primary-schooler

My nephew is 10 years old, he does not read the exam questions properly which leads to many mistakes although he knows the answer, what can I do ?

Comment: In what sense does he not read properly? Does he have dislexia? Does he have a hard time understanding the meaning? Or does he just skim over the text? Or is there a problem with presentation, e.g. to small or awkward font, to few space around the questions. Please specify.

Comment: Could you add some context (e.g. which country you're from, the education system)?

Comment: *"First you read the entire exam and you see if there is any question you don't understand. Only after that you start answering the questions. You didn't do what I say? Then don't ever bother crying to me for your bad points!"*

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you ask him questions verbally, does he listen to the question or give answers that don't exactly address what was being asked? (I've definitely known adults that would do this - I know a few people who have a strong tendency to, for example, answer the question they think you *should* have asked or answer a question that's very much like what was asked but not the actual question you were asking).

Comment: I don't know how to help, but I can share a little personal story. I could recite the standard faulty "proof" that 2=1 when I was 9. I self-taught trig and derivatives from my dad's old high school math book when I was 12. I have a master's in algebraic geometry. I have always loved math, and always been pretty decent at it. When I was 12, my class had a math test. My dad still, to this day, teases me about that test with "You know, when the big hand points to 12, and the little hand points to 3, what time is it?". The issue got better on its own eventually.

Comment: I know a kid well who has similar problems and their teacher offered the following hints, for example in maths questions, and it seems to have worked. Interact with the question rather than just reading it. Highlight things like the operation (plus, times, etc), underline key words in questions, circle important things in texts. The end result isn't the important thing: doing things with the question helps them linger and consider each part. I agree with the ADHD thing in part, it is definitely an ADHD-spectrum behaviour (though not unique to it), but that doesn't bring the pigs in.

Comment: Dima, could it be, maybe, conceivably, that he doesn’t read exam questions “properly” because he is not interested in them? How closely do you read things you’re not interested in?

Answer (score 32):

In primary school, there's three major things kids are learning:

1. Key underlying concepts/ways of thinking that will make learning more "adult" concepts possible later.
2. Study/work habits.
3. Social behavior

It sounds like your nephew is okay on 1., but is deficient in 2., study/work habits.  Assuming you're in position to help him here (I don't know your relationship with him/the parents/etc.), things you can do to help:

- Practice reading the question fully. A good way to do this is with "trick questions" - if for example this is for math, there's *lots* of examples online of trick math questions (as some people find them fun!).
- Work with him on more complex questions.  Maybe he finds the work boring?  Then consider doing some logic type questions that do require really reading the question to understand the answer.
- If he finishes the exam early, get him in the habit of going back over it, instead of handing it in early.  Maybe he feels time pressure!  Answer all the questions in one pass, then with no time pressure look them each over again to see if he got them right.
- If he is someone affected by external rewards - set up a reward system.
- Practice reading the exam questions.  Do an exam at home where *you* read the questions out loud before he does the exam.  Do an exam at home where he has to read all of the questions out loud.

Finally, two suggestions:

- Talk to the teacher and get suggestions there.  The teacher probably is aware that he knows the material.
- Talk to you nephew and see what he thinks will help.  He's 10 - that's old enough to have some ideas here! He may appreciate the consideration.

I've worked with quite a few kids who have this issue - both of mine, for one, but I also work with math-interested kids in an after school program, and plenty of them make these kinds of mistakes.  Focusing on checking work and on carefully reading the questions is a *really* valuable thing for later in life - I can't tell you the difference between an employee who reads the instructions carefully and one who skims over them and assumes they know the answer!

Comment: Anecdotally, I did not get the point of reading through questions from front to back until around 10 years old, when a problem sheet given by a teacher explicitly listed out a huge list of directions, then at the end gave a very short instruction to complete - so I can vouch for the value of a practical example for why it is important to read all the directions first.

Comment: I don't have kids, but I definitely was similar to OP's kid at that age. One other bullet point I may humbly suggest: the child may not care much. When I was that age, I knew when I knew the answer... and proving it to the teacher wasn't always a top priority. This is related to the "maybe he finds the work boring" aspect, but is also slightly different. Unfortunately, I don't remember how I got past that.

Comment: An easy way to show the value of following instructions is a test along the lines of [How Well Can You Follow Directions Test](https://www.justriddlesandmore.com/direct.html).

Comment: Joe, kids don’t learn social behavior in school. They learn how to endure unchosen associations.

Answer (score 19):

**Get him tested for ADHD/ADS**

Yes I know "everyone has it" these days and what not but what you describe (skimming over questions) fits in 100%.

Oh and even if he's an otherwise rather quiet kid that "doesn't show any other symptoms": That's very easily possible as well, the clichés don't hold all-around and even 10 year old kids can be quite skilled at masking the more negatively-received obvious symptoms.

A negative test would land you back here but would at least rule out this possible necessity for different treatment.
And a positive diagnosis would open up a completely new field of advice, tipps and strategies to help him deal with the issues he's facing.

Comment: @DennisHackethal People who suffer from ADHD may have the symptoms regardless of whether they like doing a task or not. These diseases are established in psychology as very real things for way too long and the fact that people, especially parents, still ignore them is abusive to those suffering. Please look into the topic more before uttering such statements.

Comment: Disagreement != ignorance. Have any of the kids ‘diagnosed’ with ‘ADHD’ not been subjected to coercive environments? Btw ‘ADHD’ isn’t the first fake diagnosis to explain away healthy resistance to coercion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drapetomania

Comment: @DennisHackethal stop deleting your  comments if you want to actually have a discourse instead of spewing your antivaxx-style propaganda lies.

Comment: @DennisHackethal it's not even worth discussing with you how fundamentally wrong you are about ADHS or it's diagnosis because the base assumptions in your last comment just display a quite deranged view on the world

Comment: @DennisHackethal btw. how exactly is OPs problem a display of "healthy resistance to coercion? Because even IF that is what the kid wants to display, it is a really really bad way at doing so and ADS-focused therapy could help him find more productive (or notiveable) ways.

Comment: I don’t delete my comments, the moderators do so without my knowledge or consent. Re your question: OP’s nephew does not pay attention to something he is not interested in. That’s normal and healthy. It’d be weird if he readily spent time doing things he didn’t want to do. But I’m not sure why you deem a discussion with me worthless but then proceed to ask me a question anyway. Not sure why you sound so angry, either, or what my stance has to do with anti vaxxers (I’m generally pro vaccines).

Comment: @DennisHackethal because you deny the existence of a medical condition. That is why I associate you with antivaxxers in their denial of established facts.  And I did not suggest putting the kid on Ritalin immediately, which is what you sounded like. I proposed getting him tested. Which has absolutely 0 bearing on anything. And btw 99% of people are living in "coercive environments" aka "having to pay attention to something we're not interested in". That is just modern life. The issue is that (OP beliefes that) he is not coping with that in a good way. And an ADS test could answer why.

Comment: @DennisHackethal and before you go off random tangents again: Not answer why he's reacting to the environment, but why he is responding the way he is, and could offer new avenues to teach him proven working methods to react to these environments in ways that are better for him in the long term. I really don't get what your issue even is besides the absurd implied claim  that "everyone is like that / has ADHS"

Comment: I didn’t say everyone has ADHD. And no, the way to help someone deal with coercion is not to diagnose them with a fake disease but to stop the coercion. The fact that coercion is, sadly, a reality of life is no excuse to perpetrate it against innocent children. That would be like saying that slaves shouldn’t have made a fuss because slavery was a reality of life. Moral progress is possible and should be actively attempted.

Comment: @DennisHackethal aaaaaand there you are again. By making the absurd claim that ADHD is a fake disease you are directly implying that everyone has ADHD. Because if it's not real those symptoms are just normal human behavior, aka everyone "has it". Your weird rant about the education system is a completely separate topic and absolutely, 100% unhelpful to OP. Btw. please stop slandering this important social quest with your "the moon landing was fake"-level of science denial.

Comment: @DennisHackethal and your slavery comparison is just absolutely disgusting. A better equivalent would be your refusal to diagnose suicidal people with depression because that's just a natural response to our coercive society. Killing yourself is the natural choice lmao. That is directly your logic reapplied to a slightly different scope. To clear it up: Yes our world is shit but killing yourself is NOT a healthy reply in any way. As is """"intentionally""" (another thing you have vapously claimed without any evidence) not answering test questions correctly

Comment: Just because ADHD isn’t a real disease doesn’t mean everyone responds to coercion in the same way. *Many* people have trouble concentrating on things they are not interested in, which is healthy and normal, but some others learn to force themselves to concentrate anyway, and then they’re not ‘diagnosed’. I agree that suicidal thoughts are not healthy, but I think you’re creating a straw man. Adults see a problem with *healthy* behavior in children, not unhealthy behavior. ADHD is an inversion of the concept of disease.

Comment: @DennisHackethal uhm, nobody is saying that it's a disease. that's your strawman. It's a condition. In addition one that doesn't need to be viewed as negative. It's just one where some help in dealing with the coercive-normative society that we live in can be incredibly helpful. and that is my entire point that you violently refuse to even consider. But you are clueless what you're talking about, what ADHD therapy actually entails so you do the boomer thing of pretending its not a real condition. It is. You can do brain scans of people and tell if they have ADHD. You are about as helpful as

Comment: as the people claiming it's a disease. Which is: actively harmful to a lot of kids if you had any influence on the matter. You are equally as bad as the (sadly real) doctors handing out Meth like skittles just so those kids remain calm in the classroom.

Comment: "nobody is saying that it's a disease" ADHD is internationally classified as a disease by the WHO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder#International_Classification_of_Diseases

Comment: @DennisHackethal damn, your reading skills really did stop developing after middle school. it's calssified as a disorder. Your own link states that very very clearly. And while we could argue that classification, you're obviously far away from being able to participate in an actual discussion on the topic

Comment: Your hostility and personal attacks tell me you’re the one “far away from being able to participate in an actual discussion [...]”. However, I was mistaken about ADHD being classified as a disease. So, correction: ADHD is an inversion of the concept of disorder.

Answer (score 10):

#### Test for dyslexia

It's often found in people with ADHD, but it can be in anyone. He may not be reading the question properly in the first place.

If you do ADHD testing, they probably also do dyslexia testing. It's worth having it looked at.

Answer (score 2):

Kids have multiple ways of learning (visual, auditory, kinetic) and multiple ways of expressing (same.) Some kids for any number of reasons do better in s non traditional test taking situation. Some do better having the question read to them and giving on oral answer. Talk or have his patents to the teacher and discuss strengths and relative weaknesses in his style of learning. It could be something classic like ADHD or it could be something else that just requires more skills such as answer contributor one addressed. Don't hesitate going up the ladder tho. Teacher to principal to district if u need to. School districts have psychologists who can also test for neurodivergent types if learning. If a child is seen by a private educational psychologist the school can still utilize the evaluation outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Teach the kid exactly the skill you want the kid to have - namely, spotting errors of understanding.

Don't give the kid questions on problem X.  Give the kid questions and answers, where the answer misunderstood the question, and get the kid to find the mistake.

Similarly, give the kid a pile of questions that they *know* are misleading and have them find the trick.

Naturally you start with modeling before you get them to work on it - give them questions and answers that misunderstand and someone pointing out the misunderstanding.  Give them misleading questions, with someone pointing out how they are misleading.  This step is easy to think you can skip, but it really does make the problem easier.

Don't ask the kid "did you check for misunderstandings?" - make the kid *good* at spotting misunderstandings, and then the kid will do it themselves because the effort will be much lower and the habit will be built in.

For mathematics in particular, one of the points of mathematics isn't figuring out what the answer is but *proving* that is the answer to the person reading it, so that the reader doesn't have to know the answer is right to be convinced.

A lot of mathematics education doesn't stress this nearly enough in my opinion.  "Show your work" isn't about convincing the teacher that the *kid* isn't cheating, it is providing the evidence that the *answer* is right by showing the path to get there.  And if you are showing your work in a mathematics answer, you are going to be referring back to the question in the answer in order to show that the answer actually answers the question.  A misunderstood question should show up like a bright flag.

Reframing math answers as: "You are trying to convince some reader who doesn't now how to do the math what the answer is.  They can follow along an check each tiny steps, but they can't do any leaps." might provide motivation.

Answer (score 1):

As if you don't have enough to think about... if some of the other suggestions don't seem to help, please consider if it is possible your nephew has a reading difficulty that might be more apparent in the stress or haste of reading exam questions. Reading is an amazingly complex skill of muscle and brain coordination even though it seems simple. Many subtle problems can develop, just as they do in speech (or gymnastics, etc.) and most can be corrected *once they are detected.* At least in the US, you can't rely on the customary school vision tests - they only detect a small fraction of vision/reading problems.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR The test is testing something different than your nephew (and you?) think it does.

Tests are not just testing the knowledge of the covered material, they are *also* testing *meta-*knowledge *about testing itself*. For example:

1. Can this person follow detailed instruction?
2. Can this person clearly communicate to another human being through the medium of writing that they have knowledge of the material being covered?
3. (For the cynical) Can this person "tune" their ingestion of the material for easily digestible compartmentalized chunks of information that are likely to show up on a test by virtue of being easy to test for?

This is possibly a good part of why even though ability in a specific subject might vary (e.g. good at Language Arts, bad at Math or vice-versa) for a given student their grades tend to be well-correlated *across* subjects.

If your nephew (or you) believe that testing is about whether or not he understands the subject matter...well, you're not *wrong* per se but there is more to it than that.